# 90 degree phase shift in transistor network

Tags: led, transistors, amplifier

I am analyzing an amplifier circuit that looks like the following:

[image: IR Headphone Schematic]

The input signal is provided by the 60 Hz sine wave generator.

When I ran the transient analysis on the potential of the signal and the current through the two LEDs, I got the following (interesting) plot:

[image: IR Headphone Transient Analysis]

Wow! It appears that the current through the LEDs is -90 degrees out of phase with the input. However, I have learned that it is supposed to be 180 degrees out of phase, because the transistor has a negative gain with no phase shift. Why is this so? Am I neglecting some important detail?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a clue - the current is varying from 10.9pA to 12.2pA (that's 10^-12 Amps).

Comment: You're measuring voltage and current, so that's not a surprising result for anything AC with capacitance (the transistors). Also your NPN input stage isn't biased to do anything.

Comment: @Captainj2001 Thank you very much. I understand the situation now. But is the NPN transistor not biased by the 9V DC power supply?

Comment: The base needs to be biased in addition to the collector. You need the base voltage to be at least 0.7V higher than the emitter for anything to happen in this circuit. Look up common emitter amplifier circuits and look at the biasing schemes used.

Comment: @Captainj2001 I see now. Thanks again for your help.